# How to uninstall Skype for Business Web App Plug-in on Mac?

Tags: macos, skype, uninstall, skype-for-business

Installed this today and don't see it in the applications folder.  I think the program used to be called Lync before it was changed to "Skype for Business".  Anyway, I have no idea where the files are being stored and more importantly how they can be uninstalled.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you seeing it installed? If it's in Chrome, Firefox or Safari, use their corresponding Extension manager to remove it.

Comment: That's the thing, when I look in my Chrome extensions it's not there.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a free uninstall tool like [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/). If you already threw the app in the trash, counterintutively, you'd need to reinstall it to get AppCleaner to work.

There are a few standard places where packaged apps install their files, but it's not easy to look by hand. There's your library, the system library, and so on. I feel it's better to automate this process than attempt to do it by hand.

Another option is a cleanup tool like CleanMyMac, it's a paid tool, but is built for removing application remnants.